# HOW TO? Uninstalled 'I2P' (Java application) but 'I2P' still starting java service after system startup

Tags: command-line, java, uninstall, openjdk, autostart

I installed [I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/download) on my Ubuntu 14.04 (latest updates, openjdk-8-jre) using `java -jar i2pinstall_0.9.28.jar -console`.

After playing around with it, I uninstalled it by `sudo java -jar uninstaller.jar`, which is in I2P's uninstaller directory. However, there is a hidden folder `.I2P` in my home directory, which was not removed during this process. I don't know why.

Upon system start, I2P still executes a java process which is in different directory (e.g. usr/lib/jvm/...) and I can see network traffic (`nethogs`). It seems like it's the I2P router that is being tried to be executed, no cron job in place for this.

How to find out which entry/file leads to the automated startup? Here is the corresponding endlessly long line from `htop`:

```
21307 ?        Sl     0:53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp "/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/BOB.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/commons-el.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/commons-logging.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/desktopgui.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/i2p.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/i2psnark.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/i2ptunnel.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jasper-compiler.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jasper-runtime.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/javax.servlet.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jbigi.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-continuation.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-deploy.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-http.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-i2p.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-io.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-java5-threadpool.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-rewrite-handler.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-security.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-servlet.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-servlets.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-sslengine.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-start.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-util.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-webapp.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jetty-xml.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jrobin.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/jstl.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/mstreaming.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/org.mortbay.jetty.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/org.mortbay.jmx.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/routerconsole.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/router.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/sam.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/standard.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/streaming.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/systray.jar:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib/wrapper.jar" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false -Djava.library.path=/home/JohnDoe/ItoP:/home/JohnDoe/ItoP/lib -Di2p.dir.base=/home/JohnDoe/ItoP -DloggerFilenameOverride=logs/log-router-@.txt net.i2p.router.RouterLaunch
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo apt remove i2p
sudo apt remove i2prouter
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

If you also installed an i2p daemon:
also do this before `autoremove`: `sudo apt remove i2pd`

In case the above cmd lines didn't remove the `.i2p/` dir in your home dir, you can manually remove it: `cd ~; rm -R .i2p`